# Enter data into input fields with SafariDriver - Java

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, safaridriver

I get the Safari browser to open and load the page, however, it does not enter any data into input fields.

Below is some similar code for input I'm trying to do.

```
driver = new SafariDriver();
driver.get(url);
driver.findElement(By.id("username")).sendKeys("user");
```

Comment: Is your driver and browser up to date?

Comment: Yes. I got the latest of both and running Selenium 2.46 via Eclipse

Comment: Does the same code work with other drivers? Try FF for example?

Comment: @JeffC Yes, it is working with FF, Chrome and PhantomJS drivers. I've seen, while researching, it may have something to do with iframes within Safari, I'm just not familiar with that and none of the attempts to convert the driver objects to frame did me any good. I'm completely stumped.

Comment: Unless the page is completely different in Safari and contains an IFRAME where it doesn't in other browsers, I think it's unlikely that it's related to that. I'm stumped also... have you tried downgrading?